# Getting promise instead of callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, callback

I am using the provider as mentioned in this [url](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/more-responsive-single-page-applications-with-angularjs-socketio-creating-the-library--cms-21738.), Its working fine using callback.

I was trying to return a promise instead on callback and I have added onPromise method, the modified code as below:

```
this.$get = function esseSocketFactory($rootScope,$q) {

    var socket = io.connect(ioUrl);
    var defered = $q.defer();
    return {
        on: function on(event, callback){
            socket.on(event, function(){
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        onPromise: function onPromise(event){
          socket.on(event,function(){
            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
              defered.resolve(socket);
            });
          });
          return defered.promise;
        },
```

The problem I am facing is in controller we are getting the data only once, but the **onPromise : defered.resolve(socket);** method is executed whenever the data is pushed from server. After injecting the socket my controller calls

```
socket.onPromise('status').then(function(socket){
    console.log(socket);
});
```

the *console.log* is called only once. Also the socket printed in console using promise and callback are different. Callback prints the data but promise gives me the socket object which have lots of methods and other things in it (not data).

Comment: a promise can only be resolved/rejected once - which is why you are seeing that console log only once

Comment: Use `return $q.resolve(...)` or `return $q.reject(...)`. This returns a resolved or rejected promise.